# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when opening NgModal from checkbox

Tags: angular, primeng

I know their already exists tons of questions about `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` but I'm new to Angular and I can't find a usecase that is similar to mine.

I've already read [Everything you need to know about the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/) which is really great and give me a nice understanding of why this Exception is being thrown.

My code is the following: I've got a `checkbox` (coming from `PrimeNg` library) and I want to display a dialog using `NgModal` once my checkbox is being checked.

The checkbox is a cell of a `mat-table`.

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="billingLines" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Other columns here ... -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="isPeriod">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Period </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index;">
            <p-checkbox *ngIf='canDisplayPeriodCheck(i)'
                        (onChange)='onPeriodCheck(i, $event)'></p-checkbox>      
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- mat-table definition ... -->
</table>
```

**JS**

```
onPeriodSelected(lineIndex: number, checked: boolean) {
    if (checked) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PeriodPickerComponent);
    }
}
```

I already tried to wrap the opening of my modal inside`setTimeout()` or `Promise.resolve(null).then()` but I'm still getting the same Exception.

Many thanks.

Comment: Replicate the issue on stackblitz so we can help you.

Comment: Can we see the code of `canDisplayPeriodCheck`?